# rxjs TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-subscriptions

I am facing an error triggered after subscribing to an Observable like so.

```
ngOnInit() {
    const defaultTitle = 'Something';
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => {
          const child = this.route.firstChild;
          if (child?.snapshot?.data.title) {
            return `${child.snapshot.data.title} | ${defaultTitle}`;
          }
          // fallback
          return defaultTitle;
        }),
        switchMap(title =>  {
          this.titleService.setTitle(title);
          return this.initialiseOffers() // returns Observable<{data: Offers;}>
        })
      ).subscribe((state) => {
        this.handleRedirect(state.data)
      });
      
}

handleRedirect(offers: Offers) {
  this.router.navigate(['offers'], {
          replaceUrl: true,
        });
  }
}
```

Error thrown is

> ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected.
> You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array,
> AsyncIterable, or Iterable.

This is coming from the router.navigate invocation when I examine my stack trace, but I cant figure out what's the actual cause of my error.

I am using switchMap to switch to another observable, but I dont need the result of the outer observable, only that I need to wait for that outer one to complete. I'm wondering if this is possibly a cause of my issue?

Can someone kindly point me in the right direction here please - and yes I am a bit of newbie with rxjs, so please be kind :D

Thanks

Comment: it seems you return undefined from `this.initialiseOffers()`

Comment: @Andrei - thanks for your reply, I should have mentioned in the question, that the initialiseOffers call, does return an observable and in the subscribe I am seeing its response value correctly, its not undefined.

Comment: that was the only place which could cause that problem in the code that you've provided

Comment: based on the code its in `this.initialiseOffers()` but if you say its not the case, post it so we can see.

Comment: add `const o = this.initialiseOffers(); console.log("I got an observable:", !!o); return o` to prove you really are returning an observable

Comment: I agree, it must be `this.inititalOffers`. Are you sure you didn't miss a return statement there? Just include the implementation please.